# Serving Webp images in dated folders in nginx

Tags: nginx, webp

I want to serve webp images to my visitors my images are in /img folder and they are grouped by date... So my folders look like this: /img/2022/01, /img/2021/12 etc

i want to create a webp folder inside each folder and put all my web files there. like: /img/2022/01/webp

And i want nginx to serve the webp file if its available. It works if the webp file is in the same folder, but i couldnt find a way to direct /webp folder.

I tried this config:

```
location ~* ^/(img/\d\d\d\d/\d\d)/.*\.jpe?g {
    try_files webp/$request_basename$webp_suffix $uri =404;
    expires 365d;
}
```

However its not working. Any recommendations?

Comment: Do you mean to try `/img/2022/01/webp/filename.webp` first when you got a request like `/img/2022/01/filename.jpg`? What is that `$webp_suffix` variable and how is it defined?

Comment: Yes, im trying to achieve exactly that. $web_suffix returns .webp extension name.

Comment: How is `$webp_suffix` defined? Add the corresponding configuration fragment to your question. Where is that `$request_basename` variable come from?

Comment: Solved by adding this:

map $request_uri $directory_only {
    "~(?<u>.*\/)"  $u;
    default $request_uri;
}